# Paradoxical issue with mocha done() and async await

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, async-await, mocha.js

I have the following test case:

```
it("should pass the test", async function (done) {
        await asyncFunction();
        true.should.eq(true);
        done();
    });
```

Running it asserts:

> Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or*
>   return a Promise; not both.

And if I remove the `done();` statement, it asserts:

> Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure
>   "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

How to solve this paradox?

Comment: When you remove the `done();`, do you also remove the `done` parameter in the function?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a return statement ? I was under the impression all sync function requires return to resolve.

Comment: @ShyamBabu: No, they resolve with `undefined` once the last promise they wait on is complete if there's no explicit `return`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I just removed the done parameter in the func signature, and it's working! Please rewrite it as an answer and I will accept that.

Comment: @Alon: LOL, once I proved to myself that was the issue, I was indeed writing it up. There now. :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to remove the `done` parameter as well, not just the call to it. Testing frameworks like Mocha look at the function's parameter list (or at least its arity) to know whether you're using `done` or similar.

Using Mocha 3.5.3, this works for me (had to change `true.should.be(true)` to `assert.ok(true)` as the former threw an error):

```
const assert = require('assert');

function asyncFunction() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 10);
    });
}

describe('Container', function() {
  describe('Foo', function() {
    it("should pass the test", async function () {
        await asyncFunction();
        assert.ok(true);
    });
  });
});
```

But if I add `done`:

```
describe('Container', function() {
  describe('Foo', function() {
    it("should pass the test", async function (done) {  // <==== Here
        await asyncFunction();
        assert.ok(true);
    });
  });
});
```

...then I get

> Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

Comment: You savedddd me, wasted hours looking for a solution

Comment: @T.J Crowder
following on it("should pass... still got a problem "Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves."

Comment: @AljohnYamaro - The promise in the example above *does* resolve. It waits for the promise returned by `asyncFunction` to resolve, then calls `assert.ok(true)`, then resolves (by returning).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the version I used is 3.5.3 with this code, https://www.screencast.com/t/9sLDqnlLb got return fron console.log, but still the problem is Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. I guess you can help me. Thank you

Comment: @AljohnYamaro - You'll need to post a new question with a [mcve] of your code (not a *picture* of it). Your code is using things not used above, so that may be complicating things.

Comment: okay thank you @T.J.Crowder but my account is prevented to ask questions again.

Comment: @AljohnYamaro - Ouch, I'm sorry to hear that. Also a bit surprised, looking at your activity. I guess there must be deleted stuff. If you want to put something in a gist or on pastebin or some such that I can copy and paste into a `test.js` file, I'm happy to take a quick look just in case something jumps out at me.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I guess there is no need, I found the solution. On package.json should be "test": "mocha --timeout 60000" before was "test": "mocha" only that is why it says Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

In short, time must be lengthened. Your solution works too. Thank you.

Comment: bless you!!! seriously. wasted dont know how many hours because of this

Answer (score 0):

Removing done as a param from it worked for me! Instead only use expect/should. Example is as follows:

```
getResponse(unitData, function callBack(unit, error, data){ try {
    return request.post(unit, function (err, resp) {
        if (!err && resp.statusCode === 200) {
            if (resp.body.error) {
                return callback(obj, JSON.stringify(resp.body.error), null); 
            }
            return callback(obj, null, resp); 
        } else {
            if (err == null) {  
                err = { statusCode: resp.statusCode, error: 'Error occured.' };
            }
            return callback(obj, err, null); 
        }
    });
} catch (err) {
    return callback(obj, err, null);
}}
```

BEFORE:

```
it('receives successful response', async (done) => { 
const getSomeData = await getResponse(unitData, function callBack(unit, error, data){ 
    expect(data.statusCode).to.be.equal(200); 
    done(); 
}) })
```

AFTER (works):

```
it('receives successful response', async () => { 
const getSomeData = await getResponse(unitData, function callBack(unit, error, data){
     expect(data.statusCode).to.be.equal(200); 
}) })
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there are cases you need to use `async/await` + `done` function in mocha.

For example, in one of my `socket.io` unit test cases, I have to call db functions with async functions and test socket event handlers which are callback functions:

```js
context("on INIT_CHAT", ()=> {
  it("should create a room", async (done) => {
    const user = await factory.create("User");
    socket.emit("INIT_CHAT", user);
    
    socket.on("JOIN_CHAT", async (roomId) => {
       const room = await ChatRoom.findByPk(roomId);
       expect(room).to.exist;
       // then I need to close a test case here
       done();
    });
  });
});
```

This will causes the exact same error as in the OP:

> Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback or return a Promise; not both.

## My Workaround:

I just wrapped the entire test code in a promise generator:

```js
context("on INIT_CHAT", ()=> {
  it("should create a room", async () => {
    const asyncWrapper = () => {
      return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
        const user = await factory.create("User");
        socket.emit("INIT_CHAT", user);
        socket.on("JOIN_CHAT", async (roomId) => {
          const room = await ChatRoom.findByPk(roomId);
          expect(room).to.exist;
          resolve(true);
        });
      });
    });
    await asyncWrapper();
  });
});
```