# Test with Promise not entering then/catch

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, testing

I have the following test

```
describe('User - Sign up', function() {
 it('should not register a new user because of missing data on form', function (done) {
    const email = "testemail@gmail.com";
    const req = { body: { email: email }};

    const signUp = controller.signUp(req);

    console.log(signUp);
    signUp
        .then(data => {
            console.log('ok');
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('error')
        });

    done();
});
```

being signUp function the following:

```
return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
    validator.checkAsync(async () => {
        const user = {
            email: req.body.email,
            password: await pwdHash.hashPassword(req.body.password)
        }

        await store.signUp(user);

        resolve({
            valid: true
        });
    }, () => {
        reject(validator.errors);
    });
}));
```

However, the test is not returning any console log and it's going through.
What am I missing?

UPDATE:

I was able to fix it with the following code:

```
    it('should not register a new user when missing data on form', async function () {
    const email = "testemail@gmail.com";

    const res = await chai.request('http://localhost:3000')
        .post('/user/signup',)
        .send({ email: email });

    expect(res).to.have.status(401);
});
```

based on comments and this comment: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46217308/868699

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `done` before the `Promise` fulfils.

```
signUp
        .then(data => done())
        .catch(done);
```

If it enters the `.catch`, `done` will be called with `error`, failing the test. If the argument passed to `done` is truthy, it will fail the test (At least for `mocha`).

You can also use `async/await` syntax, and drop `done`

```
 it('should not register a new...', async function() {
    /* ... */
    await controller.signUp(req)
 });
```

Comment: I changed it to 
 `const signUp = controller.signUp(req);

        console.log(signUp);
        signUp
            .then(data => {
                console.log('ok');
                done();
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log('error')
                done();
            });
`

but it logs **Promise { <pending> }**
and it throws an error saying __Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called__

Comment: because it's taking more time than `2000ms`, increase the timeout.

Comment: Do you still have the issue?

Comment: Yes, I incremented the timeout to `11000ms` with no luck.. I'm stuck

Comment: show your updated code. And try using `async/await`

Comment: signUp returns a promise, so if I do `const signUp = await controller.signUp(req);`  the variable signUp should have the object. However, doing that and then doing `console.log(signUp)` keeps giving me timeout error

Comment: your function `signUp` never resolves, it's timing out.